# Implementing Peek to IEnumerator and IEnumerator<T>

Tags: c#

Many of you might have come to the point and wished to have a Peek for IEnumerator and IEnumerator. I tried to implement it by cheating a bit and looking up the next element before the actual MoveNext call. So I ended up with some kind of wrapper.

First of the extensions to convert default enumerators:

```
public static class PeekableEnumeratorExtension
{
    public static PeekableEnumerator ToPeekable(this IEnumerator enumerator)
    {
        return new PeekableEnumerator(enumerator);
    }

    public static PeekableEnumerator<T> ToPeekable<T>(this IEnumerator<T> enumerator)
    {
        return new PeekableEnumerator<T>(enumerator);
    }
}
```

And here is the non-generic PeekableEnumerator:

```
public class PeekableEnumerator : IEnumerator
{
    protected enum Status { Uninitialized, Starting, Started, Ending, Ended }

    protected IEnumerator enumerator;

    protected Status status;

    protected object current;

    protected object peek;

    public PeekableEnumerator(IEnumerator enumerator)
    {
        this.enumerator = enumerator;
        status = Status.Uninitialized;
        MoveNext();
    }

    public object Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (Status.Starting == status)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Enumeration has not started. Call MoveNext.");
            if (Status.Ended == status)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Enumeration already finished.");

            return current;
        }
    }

    public object Peek
    {
        get
        {
            if (Status.Ending == status || Status.Ended == status)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Enumeration already finished.");

            return peek;
        }
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        current = peek;
        switch (status)
        {
            case Status.Uninitialized:
            case Status.Starting:
                if (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    status++;
                    peek = enumerator.Current;
                }
                else
                    status = Status.Ending;
                break;
            case Status.Started:
                if (enumerator.MoveNext())
                    peek = enumerator.Current;
                else
                    status++;
                break;
            case Status.Ending:
                status++;
                break;
        }

        return Status.Ended != status;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        enumerator.Reset();
        status = Status.Uninitialized;
        MoveNext();
    }
}
```

And the very analog PeekableEnumerator:

```
public class PeekableEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<T>
{
    protected enum Status { Uninitialized, Starting, Started, Ending, Ended }

    protected IEnumerator<T> enumerator;

    protected Status status;

    protected T current;

    protected T peek;

    public PeekableEnumerator(IEnumerator<T> enumerator)
    {
        this.enumerator = enumerator;
        status = Status.Uninitialized;
        MoveNext();
    }

    public T Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (Status.Starting == status)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Enumeration has not started. Call MoveNext.");
            if (Status.Ended == status)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Enumeration already finished.");

            return current;
        }
    }

    object System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current { get { return Current; } }

    public T Peek
    {
        get
        {
            if (Status.Ending == status || Status.Ended == status)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Enumeration already finished.");

            return peek;
        }
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        current = peek;
        switch (status)
        {
            case Status.Uninitialized:
            case Status.Starting:
                if (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    status++;
                    peek = enumerator.Current;
                }
                else
                    status = Status.Ending;
                break;
            case Status.Started:
                if (enumerator.MoveNext())
                    peek = enumerator.Current;
                else
                    status++;
                break;
            case Status.Ending:
                status++;
                break;
        }

        return Status.Ended != status;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        enumerator.Reset();
        status = Status.Uninitialized;
        MoveNext();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        enumerator.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Before you ask: Why are there 5 statuses? It is derived from the lifetime of Current and Peek:

```
Status        | Current   | Peek      | Comment
--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------------------------------
Uninitialized | n/a       | n/a       | Internal for constructor and Reset
Starting      | Exception | Available | Before first MoveNext
Started       | Available | Available | After first MoveNext
Ending        | Available | Exception | wrapped MoveNext returned false
Ended         | Exception | Exception | After enumeration finished
```

Example usage:

```
var a = new[] { 1, 2, 3 }.GetEnumerator().ToPeekable();

a.Current; // InvalidOperationException
a.Peek; // 1
a.MoveNext(); // true
a.Current; // 1
a.Peek; // 2
a.MoveNext(); // true
a.Current; // 2
a.Peek; // 3
a.MoveNext(); // true
a.Current; // 3
a.Peek; // InvalidOperationException
a.MoveNext(); // false
a.Current; // InvalidOperationException
a.Peek; // InvalidOperationException
```

**Update**

Thanks to [svick](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/2041/svick) here is an alternative version using a Queue. It changes the basic usage from IEnumerator to ICollection as input but I can live with that. I need to keep an copy of the original collection for resetting.

```
public class PeekableEnumerator : IEnumerator
{
    protected ICollection collection;

    protected Queue queue;

    protected bool current_set;

    protected object current;

    protected bool peek_set;

    protected object peek;

    public object Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (!current_set)
                if (peek_set)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Enumeration has not started. Call MoveNext.");
                else
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Enumeration already finished.");

            return current;
        }
    }

    public object Peek
    {
        get
        {
            if (!peek_set)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Enumeration already finished.");

            return peek;
        }
    }

    public PeekableEnumerator(ICollection collection)
    {
        this.collection = collection;
        Reset();
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        current_set = peek_set;
        current = peek;

        if (0 == queue.Count)
        {
            peek_set = false;
            return current_set;
        }
        else
        {
            peek_set = true;
            peek = queue.Dequeue();
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        queue = new Queue(collection);
        MoveNext();
    }
}
```

Comment: While I applaud the effort, I doubt its usage, when and why would you want or need to peek without just iterating?

Comment: @Davio Peek is very useful when you make decisions based on the next value inside of a loop without consuming the value.

Comment: @eisberg Have you considered using `Queue<T>` instead? I think that's much more natural most of the time. `Queue<T>` is not lazy, but I never needed that in such cases.

Comment: @eisberg, Well, that doesn't really answer my question. I'm looking for a real-world scenario where you would actually want to use it. What do you use it for?

Comment: @Davio A parser for example.

Comment: @Davio, how about a query against a database that prepares for a couple of minutes and returns more rows than you have RAM for? Say, you want to to look at first row of the sequence of results (or just its metadata) and do some preparation before starting the iteration that can go for hours? That is exactly the reason IEnumerable was created in the first place: to avoid storing more than one row of the sequence in RAM

Comment: I generally ignore comments based on universal rules to software development not based on a specification; but especially when only the rule is stated and not supporting evidence.

Comment: This is exceptionally useful as a parsing helper. I wrote a parser that implemented 2-4 of these in parallel for different look-ahead requirements. Also, an `Any()` function is helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your implementation is too complicated, and what nagged me was that you start enumerate in constructor. Here is my implementation which fix that. The state reduced to a boolean telling that the peek value has been fetched from the underlying enumerator or not.

```
public class PeekEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<T>
{
    private IEnumerator<T> _enumerator;
    private T _peek;
    private bool _didPeek;

    public PeekEnumerator(IEnumerator<T> enumerator)
    {
        if (enumerator == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("enumerator");
        _enumerator = enumerator;
    }

    #region IEnumerator implementation
    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        return _didPeek ? !(_didPeek = false) : _enumerator.MoveNext();
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        _enumerator.Reset();
        _didPeek = false;
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current { get { return this.Current; } }
    #endregion

    #region IDisposable implementation
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _enumerator.Dispose();
    }
    #endregion

    #region IEnumerator implementation
    public T Current
    {
        get { return _didPeek ? _peek : _enumerator.Current; }
    }
    #endregion

    private void TryFetchPeek() {
        if (!_didPeek && (_didPeek = _enumerator.MoveNext()))
        {
            _peek = _enumerator.Current;
        }
    }

    public T Peek
    {
        get { 
            TryFetchPeek();
            if (!_didPeek)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Enumeration already finished.");

            return _peek;
        }
    }
}
```

My test to make sure it complies to your needed behaviour:

```
var a = new PeekEnumerator<int>(new [] { 1, 2, 3 }.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator());
Console.WriteLine(a.Peek); // 1
Console.WriteLine(a.MoveNext()); // true
Console.WriteLine(a.Current); // 1
Console.WriteLine(a.Peek); // 2
Console.WriteLine(a.MoveNext()); // true
Console.WriteLine(a.Current); // 2
Console.WriteLine(a.Peek); // 3
Console.WriteLine(a.MoveNext()); // true
Console.WriteLine(a.Current); // 3

try {
    Console.WriteLine(a.Peek); // InvalidOperationException
}
catch (Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine(e.GetType());
}

Console.WriteLine(a.MoveNext()); // false

try {
    Console.WriteLine(a.Current); // InvalidOperationException
}
catch (Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine(e.GetType());
}

try {
    Console.WriteLine(a.Peek); // InvalidOperationException
}
catch (Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine(e.GetType());
}
```

Comment: This nice but it does not throw an InvalidOperationException before the first use of MoveNext on Current. See my example usage.

Comment: It does. It relies on the exception thrown by the underlying enumerator in that case.

Comment: Sorry. I tested with List<int>(...) which returns default(...) instead of throwing an InvalidOperationException.

Comment: Seems they are different implementation between List and Array. According to MSDN documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.current.aspx, the Current property should be undefined on created instead of throwing exception when called.

Comment: I like explicit exceptions over implicit values. Thank you again.

Comment: Well, also according to .NET Framework Design Guideline : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229006(v=vs.110).aspx, property should avoid raising exception but it's up to you anyway. Actually, the design has an issue that you cannot peek at the end of the enumerator, so a `HasPeek` method/property should be added to allow consumer to check on it rather than forcing consumer to try/catch the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what your question is but I have something you might want to think about, Maybe `Peek()` shouldn't throw an exception when it's out of bounds or has `Status.Ending == status || Status.Ended == status`, but instead return a null object so you can check the value of it before you decide to do something.

```
if(a.Peek != null) { ... }
```

Food for thought

Comment: This is code review. So I did not ask to review my code please :)

As null is a valid value. This is not an option.

Comment: Yes this is codereview, so anything in here will be reviewed :P But it's always a good idea to come up with some specific questions.

Comment: I see. I should have asked for improvements. Maybe.

Answer (score 1):

I changed svick's implemntation to use generics, and also changed the peek method to return bool rather than throwing an exception... although adding

```
bool TryPeek(out T value);
```

to the existing implementation might be more appropriate

```
public class PeekableEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<T>
{
    protected IEnumerable<T> collection;

    protected Queue<T> queue;

    protected bool current_set;

    protected T current;

    protected bool peek_set;

    protected T peek;

    public T Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (!current_set)
                if (peek_set)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Enumeration has not started. Call MoveNext.");
                else
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Enumeration already finished.");

            return current;
        }
    }

    public bool Peek(out T value)
    {
        value = default(T);

        if (!peek_set)
            return false;

        value = peek;
        return true;
    }

    public PeekableEnumerator(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        this.collection = collection;
        Reset();
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        current_set = peek_set;
        current = peek;

        if (0 == queue.Count)
        {
            peek_set = false;
            return current_set;
        }
        else
        {
            peek_set = true;
            peek = queue.Dequeue();
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        queue = new Queue<T>(collection);
        MoveNext();
    }

    public virtual void Dispose()
    {

    }

    object System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current
    {
        get { return Current; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Was interested in [eisberg](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/3038/eisberg) and [tia](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/24351/tia) implementations as I needed the peek functionality for a compiler project.  While I prefer the simplicity of tia's version, eisberg's State pattern was the only implementation that worked as I expected.  The bug in tia's version was because the value of Current changes after a call to Peek.  To see this, use the following test code:

```
        var a = new PeekEnumerator2<int>(new[] { 1, 2, 3 }.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator());
        Console.WriteLine(a.Peek + " Expect 1"); 
        Console.WriteLine(a.MoveNext() + " Expect true"); 
        Console.WriteLine(a.Current + " Expect 1"); 
        Console.WriteLine(a.Peek + " Expect 2");
        Console.WriteLine(a.Current + " Expect 1"); 
        Console.WriteLine(a.MoveNext() + " Expect true");
        Console.WriteLine(a.Current + " Expect 2");
        Console.WriteLine(a.Peek + " Expect 3"); 
        Console.WriteLine(a.Current + " Expect 2");
        Console.WriteLine(a.MoveNext() + " Expect true"); 
        Console.WriteLine(a.Current + " Expect 3");
```

I got the following output for tia's implementation:

```
    1 Expect 1
    True Expect true
    1 Expect 1
    2 Expect 2
    2 Expect 1  // this is wrong - current should not have changed due to call to peek
    True Expect true
    2 Expect 2
    3 Expect 3
    3 Expect 2  // this is wrong - current should not have changed due to call to peek
    True Expect true
    3 Expect 3
```

Using the same test code for eisberg's implementation I got the expected values:

```
    1 Expect 1
    True Expect true
    1 Expect 1
    2 Expect 2
    1 Expect 1
    True Expect true
    2 Expect 2
    3 Expect 3
    2 Expect 2
    True Expect true
    3 Expect 3
```

Unfortunately I couldn't quickly find a fix to tia's implementation so had to go with eisberg's state pattern.

A minor comment on eisberg's implementation:  If the source enumerator is empty (e.g. new `PeekEnumerator<int>(new[] { }.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator())`, then it doesn't set the end status correctly.  The fix is simple: just modify the switch block as follows so that `Status.Uninitialized` goes to `Status.Ended` (rather than `Status.Ending`) if the ennumerable is empty.

```
            case Status.Uninitialized:
                if (this.enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    this.status++;
                    this.peek = this.enumerator.Current;
                    break;
                }

                this.status = Status.Ended;
                break;

            case Status.Starting:
                if (this.enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    this.status++;
                    this.peek = this.enumerator.Current;
                    break;
                }

                this.state = Status.Ending;
                break;
```

Comment: Comments about other answers generally aren't necessary. Good observation about the original answer.

Comment: @pacmaninbw, DYM original *question*?